# Can I copy text from an article to complete my review article?

Tags: plagiarism, copyright

I'm currently writing an article and wonder if I could copy text from various articles. Is this appropriate?

I checked similar review articles and found they copied the abstracts for similar works, but can I copy the an introduction from another article to complete my introduction?

Answer (score 7):

You can quote verbatim, *iff*

1. the passage quoted is reasonably short (about one sentence, but not a whole paragraph);
2. and you put the quoted passage in quotation marks and/or italic;
3. and you give the reference immediately before or afterwards.

For example:

> As John & Ali (2012) have phrased it "this is a verbatim quote from
>   their publiation".

However, having said that, you should avoid excessive verbatim quotations. Quoting verbatim is frowned upon and reflects poorly on your ability to express yourself. As stated in point 1 above, quoting a whole paragraph or even more is inappropriate in any case, because it implies that your text lacks originality. The same holds for near-verbatim quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any situation in which it would be appropriate to copy a section of another article (even with acknowledgment). In particular, since your article is different from any other that has ever been written, it needs its own introduction. If a small part of some other article is highly relevant, you can quote it with attribution; if you need to refer to a longer section of text, the only reasonable way to do this is to cite their article and draw attention to the appropriate section (e.g., "This is discussed further in Section 2 of (Doe et al., 2015)").